# How can i validate that the user can only vote once using an status value in the data base?

Tags: php, validation, vote

I'm trying to make a voting system and i have this code that updates the votes in a table of the database, there's also the code to check if the user has an status of 0, if it's 0 it can vote otherwise it shouldn't be able to, when he votes that status changes to a 1, stopping it from voting again, the problem is that i'm not sure how to add in the if structure the id of the user that logged in the system.

```
include 'credenciales.php';

$conne=new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

$sql="SELECT estado FROM usuario WHERE Id = ".$_POST['id_usuario']; 

$res = $conne->query($sql);
$item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$res->free();

if ($item["estado"] == 0) {

  if (isset($_POST['match'])) {

mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

  $sqlU="UPDATE partido SET votos = votos + 1 WHERE Id = ".$_POST['match'];

  $conne->query($sqlU);
}  
else
{
  echo 'You've already voted';
}
```

I expect that if the user has 0 in the status column, then he can vote, when he votes the 0 changes to a 1 and can't vote again.

Comment: What's not working with the code you have? Apart from perhaps the fact that you're not updating the user record to indicate that they have voted.

Comment: the error is in the part when i try to get the user id, "$_POST['id_usuario']; " this part, i try doing it with session. but it didnt work for me

Comment: What does your form HTML look like?

Comment: it's just a radio button with a submit button, but do you want an image or the code?

Comment: Is the `is_usuario` field not included in the form, as a hidden input? If not, that explains why you can't access it in the `$_POST` array. And if it is, without any other security, it's not stopping anyone from changing it and voting as someone else.

Comment: Session really is the better way to go for this, I expect. If that's not working, then your problem is really nothing to do with making sure the user votes only once, but rather how to retrieve the user ID from the session.

Comment: Oh yeah the probleb was how to retrieve the user ID, but i finally did it with session, thanks for all the help.